# Is x ∗ y ≥ 0 on the Integers a transitive relation?

Tags: relations

So this textbook I'm working through is claiming that x ∗ y ≥ 0 on the Integers is a transitive relation, however this seems clearly wrong. Let x ~ y and y ~ z. If x < 0, y = 0, and z > 0, then clearly x ~ z is false, and would not be a part of the relation. What am I missing here?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're not missing anything.

Comment: The relation would be transitive if it was $x\cdot y>0,$ but not as $x\cdot y\ge 0.$

Comment: It's a transitive relation on the _non-zero_ integers. Perhaps this is what your textbook claims? Or perhaps the relation is $x\cdot y>0$?

Comment: Avoid the use of ∗ to denote multiplication. That just cause confusion.